# OpenCV - Hu Moments Descriptors, Theoretical Range of Values

Tags: image, opencv, range, shapes, descriptor

I want to know what are the theoretical minimum and maximum values possible for Hu Moments. Between what two numbers are the Hu Moments defined? [x,y].

My purpose after finding these is to normalise the data in that range.

Comment: The ranges are going to change depending on the image size and range of pixel values. All of the relevant equations are [here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#humoments) if you want to calculate them.

Comment: Just realized I never really thanked. It indeed depends on various factors. Thanks ! :)